# How should be the project architecture ( or structure ) of React + Electron?

Tags: reactjs, electron

Last week, I've started building a desktop application with [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) and I want to integrate React with it.

Electron official documentation does not provide a detailed **Framework Integration** section.

So, I've tried to do some googling and I've found a useful [article](http://people.loyno.edu/%7Erharvey/teaching/cosc-a319/2019f/converting-cra-to-electron/) about converting `Create React App` to electron application.

However, I just get confused about the project structure and how to make sure that I have everything to take my app into production ( React + Electron ) without tears in the future.

Where should I put my renderers?

How these renders can handle React Pages or React Components?

Please, would you guide me to set up React-Electron for a production-ready application?

**My current structure**

[image]

The `main.js` is the main file ( process ) for Electron.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really matter *too* much about your structure provided you have one and it makes sense.

I'm the developer of [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template), which is a react/electron template so I'll share with you the format of this project and you can use this as a template if you'd like.

```
app/
    electron/
        main.js    <-- BrowserWindow gets created here, event handlers, etc.
        menu.js    <-- Custom menu is defined here
        preload.js    <-- Preload code is here
    src/
        components/    <-- Reusable .jsx components
        core/    <-- The root wrapper element of the app (contains a store, page router)
        pages/    <-- Each page of the app (.jsx and .css).
            home/
                home.jsx
                home.css
            about/
                about.jsx
                about.css
        redux/    <-- Page routing code, may not be specific to you
        index.html    <-- Root html page
        index.jsx    <-- Root element that renders the root wrapper element
dist/    <-- Gets auto-created
node_modules/
resources/
    icon.icns
    icon.ico
    icon.png
    etc...
test/    <-- Contains test scripts
.gitignore
.babelrc
package.json
README.md
webpack.config.js
```

Comment: Please, would you share an example where should I put my renders ( just confused how to use renders with the components ).

Comment: Renders as in ReactDOM.render or a React class?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo error, I meant Electron renderers. How could each component or page have its own Electron renderer?

Comment: your proposed architecture invoked this error where I attempted atp import`renderer.js` file in my component:                                                                `Module not found: You attempted to import ../electron/renderer which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not suppor`

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin my architecture works in my template where all the paths are set up. Based on your error, try making sub folders in your src/ directory, that should avoid the error from being thrown.